# For "obtaining specific datasets" questions, let's recommend OpenData.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, on-topic

Many of the questions closed with the reason *"obtaining specific datasets"* would actually be good questions for Cross Validated's new little brother:

http://OpenData.stackexchange.com

When closing such a question, how about suggesting Open Data?

> Questions about obtaining specific datasets are [off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on Cross Validated. You are welcome to post this question to the [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com) QA site instead, thank you!

*Please note that Open Data is mostly for datasets under an open license, even though commercial datasets are usually tolerated.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that's a good idea.  Perhaps we can go one better and migrate their questions to OpenData.SE.

Comment: OK, seeing how the voting is going and not reading any objections, I made the change. For it to take effect another moderator must "de-activate" the current version and approve the new one.